# How to configure AutoMapper to map entities

Tags: c#, automapper, automapping

This is Teacher

```
public class Teacher

{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Education { get; set; }

    public string Expereince { get; set; }

    public List<Courses> Courses { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public User Users { get; set; }
}
```

I have 2 more entities, that I need mapping to DTO

```
public class AllCourseDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string TeacherName { get; set; }

    public string DateStart { get; set; }

    public string DateEnd { get; set;}
}
```

I want to map `Teacher` to `AllCoursesDTO`, could you explain, how I need tune my Mapper, that currently mapping to `AllCourseDTO`?

Comment: What you expect to map into each field of course DTO ?

Comment: At basic level you would need Mapper.CreateMap<Teacher, xxxDTO>() blah blah blah. If you want to map 3 entities into 1 DTO you would need Mapper.CreateMap<Tuple<Teacher, What, What>, xxxDTO>() blah blah blah.

Comment: You are looking for solution in the wrong place. AutoMapper should be responsible for *mapping* not for *resolving* your entities. At the moment you do not even have the data you need.